# Decreasing distance between text and edge for QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

How can we decrease the distance between the text strings inside of a `QPushButton` and the edge?

For me (on LXDE) it now looks like this:

[image: buttons-actual]

```
self.on_qpb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("On"))
hbox.addWidget(self.on_qpb)
self.on_qpb.setCheckable(True)
self.on_qpb.toggled.connect(self.on_on_toggled)
```

We're hoping for something like this:

[image: buttons-wanted]

We achieved the latter using `setFixedWidth` but that creates problems when translating into other languages

What can you recommend? Grateful for help!

Comment: i don't know if this is possible or not with an attribute but you can take the button text lenght and adjust the width acordingly something like `len(B_text0)*10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to set the width of the text according to the text with the help of `QFontMetrics`, or you can create a class that implements the logic with size policies and return an appropriate `sizeHint()` as shown in the following example:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Maximum)

    def sizeHint(self):
        w = self.fontMetrics().width(" {} ".format(self.text()))
        h = QPushButton.sizeHint(self).height()
        return QSize(w, h)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.on_qpb = QPushButton(self.tr("On"))
        self.on_qpb.setCheckable(True)
        self.on_qpb.setFixedWidth(self.on_qpb.fontMetrics().width(" {} ".format(self.on_qpb.text())))

        self.off_qpb = PushButton(self.tr("Off"))
        self.off_qpb.setCheckable(True)

        hbox.addWidget(self.on_qpb)
        hbox.addWidget(self.off_qpb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```